# Hadoop - DataNode and Namenode not starting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I installed Hadoop on Ubuntu but when I run ./start-all.sh script in sbin folder 
the DataNode and Namenode not starting. 
I got the following settings in the config files:

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.default.FS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:50071</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dhadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>usr/local/hadoop</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce-shuffle</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Could you please help me do I need to add any other information in the xml files? I have no idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Please add the log files...

Comment: By the way `dhadoop.tmp.dir` has a d at the beginning of it. And the mapred & yarn site aren't needed for the namenode / datanode, so you may want to ignore them. Try running `start-dfs` script instead

Comment: Even your facing same problem [Follow the same steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723033/7527189)

Comment: @Yordanka Stoyanova  Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307847/hadoop-namenode-not-starting-formatting-on-ubuntu) , i think its similar